# Fill in timestamp gaps every 11th of a second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a textfile 'example.txt' which contains data sampled at 11 Hz (so every 11th of a second).

Here you can find my code to load the textfile and convert 'Date' and 'Time' into datetime format. In the end the dataframe has a size of (34,6):

```
import glob
import os
import datetime

#Specify file path
file = 'C:\Users\...\example.txt'

#Load file
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", header=None, names=["Date", "Time", "ID1","ID2","ID3","MP","ET"],float_precision='round_trip')

#In my specific case, the txt.file has headers, which I want to remove
date = df['Date']
if date[0] == 'Date':
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    
# I erase the letters 'ms' so I only get numbers
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str[:-2]

# Put in datetime format
date = df['Date']
time = df['Time']
date_and_time = date + time
date_time_format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %f'
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(date_and_time,format=date_time_format)

# Drop Date column
df = df.drop(['Date'],axis=1)
```

In the 22th and 23th row (see output below), there is a gap of 35 seconds. Since I want to plot this data, I would like to fill in this gap by using the same sampling frequency of 11 Hz. So I would like to fill 35*11 datapoints between the 22th and 23th row. For this 'filled in data', I want to attribute the correct timestamp and attribute zero's to all other variables (ID1,ID2,ID3,MP and ET). I've read documentation on resampling (pandas module), but there is no option for resampling on 10th or 11th of seconds. Is there another way to do this? Maybe there is an option in plotting which accounts for gaps in timestamp data?

Thanks

```
df
Out[25]: 
                         Time ID1  ID2  ID3       MP               ET
0  2020-08-06 18:00:38.000000   0    0    0   230400   0.229000091553
1  2020-08-06 18:00:38.999160   0    1    1      529   0.254999876022
2  2020-08-06 18:00:38.199833   0    2    2      619   0.270999908447
3  2020-08-06 18:00:38.299750   0    3    3       84   0.292000055313
4  2020-08-06 18:00:38.399666   0    4    4      629    0.31500005722
5  2020-08-06 18:00:38.499583   0    5    5      376   0.331000089645
6  2020-08-06 18:00:38.599500   0    6    6      660    0.34299993515
7  2020-08-06 18:00:38.699417   0    7    7      160   0.354000091553
8  2020-08-06 18:00:38.799333   0    8    8      246   0.361999988556
9  2020-08-06 18:00:38.899250   0    9    9       69   0.371000051498
10 2020-08-06 18:00:38.999167   0   10   10      462   0.382999897003
11 2020-08-06 18:00:39.000000   0    0    0        3   0.229000091553
12 2020-08-06 18:00:39.999160   0    1    1       59   0.254999876022
13 2020-08-06 18:00:39.199833   0    2    2       19   0.270999908447
14 2020-08-06 18:00:39.299750   0    3    3        8   0.292000055313
15 2020-08-06 18:00:39.399666   0    4    4        9    0.31500005722
16 2020-08-06 18:00:39.499583   0    5    5       36   0.331000089645
17 2020-08-06 18:00:39.599500   0    6    6        6    0.34299993515
18 2020-08-06 18:00:39.699417   0    7    7       10   0.354000091553
19 2020-08-06 18:00:39.799333   0    8    8       46   0.361999988556
20 2020-08-06 18:00:39.899250   0    9    9        9   0.371000051498
21 2020-08-06 18:00:39.999167   0   10   10        2   0.382999897003
22 2020-08-06 18:01:14.000000   0   11   11      704   0.395999908447
23 2020-08-06 18:01:14.999160   0   12   12      795   0.410000085831
24 2020-08-06 18:01:14.199833   0   13   13      532   0.421000003815
25 2020-08-06 18:01:14.299750   0   14   14      363   0.430000066757
26 2020-08-06 18:01:14.399666   0    4    4      629    0.31500005722
27 2020-08-06 18:01:14.499583   0    5    5      376   0.331000089645
28 2020-08-06 18:01:14.599500   0    6    6      660    0.34299993515
29 2020-08-06 18:01:14.699417   0    7    7      160   0.354000091553
30 2020-08-06 18:01:14.799333   0    8    8      246   0.361999988556
31 2020-08-06 18:01:14.899250   0    9    9       69   0.371000051498
32 2020-08-06 18:01:14.999167   0   10   10      462   0.382999897003
33 2020-08-06 18:01:15.000000   0   11   11        4   0.395999908447
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to put into the values of these new timestamps?  It looks to me like it would be difficult to fill that data in with any good representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your timestamp as a timestamp, the missing time gap will be filled in by a line connecting the two data points on either side.  We can call out the legit values by using a scatterplot over top of the line plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Time',y='ET')
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='Time',y='ET', s=50,color='r');
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank your Chris. That would already be helpful. Is there anyway to highlight this missing data in the plot?

Comment: @Geox Update the answer, it's the easiest way I can think of to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

It would be difficult to create a new time series to fill in the missing values based on your time series because the time delta is not exactly 1/11 of a second (which would be ~ 090909090 microseconds.)

But fortunately the samples are not missing from your df, they are just out of order.

if you sort by your timeseries data you will see that you have all 11 samples per second in the provided dataframe.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Time'])
df
```

gives:

```
        Time    ID1 ID2 ID3 MP  ET  Time Offset
0   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.000000  0   0   0   230400  0.229000091553  
2   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.199833  0   2   2   619 0.270999908447  0 days 00:00:00.199833000
3   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.299750  0   3   3   84  0.292000055313  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
4   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.399666  0   4   4   629 0.31500005722   0 days 00:00:00.099916000
5   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.499583  0   5   5   376 0.331000089645  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
6   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.599500  0   6   6   660 0.34299993515   0 days 00:00:00.099917000
7   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.699417  0   7   7   160 0.354000091553  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
8   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.799333  0   8   8   246 0.361999988556  0 days 00:00:00.099916000
9   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.899250  0   9   9   69  0.371000051498  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
1   2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.999160  0   1   1   529 0.254999876022  0 days 00:00:00.099910000
10  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:38.999167  0   10  10  462 0.382999897003  0 days 00:00:00.000007000
11  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.000000  0   0   0   3   0.229000091553  0 days 00:00:00.000833000
13  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.199833  0   2   2   19  0.270999908447  0 days 00:00:00.199833000
14  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.299750  0   3   3   8   0.292000055313  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
15  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.399666  0   4   4   9   0.31500005722   0 days 00:00:00.099916000
16  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.499583  0   5   5   36  0.331000089645  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
17  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.599500  0   6   6   6   0.34299993515   0 days 00:00:00.099917000
18  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.699417  0   7   7   10  0.354000091553  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
19  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.799333  0   8   8   46  0.361999988556  0 days 00:00:00.099916000
20  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.899250  0   9   9   9   0.371000051498  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
12  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.999160  0   1   1   59  0.254999876022  0 days 00:00:00.099910000
21  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:00:39.999167  0   10  10  2   0.382999897003  0 days 00:00:00.000007000
22  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.000000  0   11  11  704 0.395999908447  0 days 00:00:34.000833000
24  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.199833  0   13  13  532 0.42100000381499997 0 days 00:00:00.199833000
25  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.299750  0   14  14  363 0.43000006675700003 0 days 00:00:00.099917000
26  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.399666  0   4   4   629 0.31500005722   0 days 00:00:00.099916000
27  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.499583  0   5   5   376 0.331000089645  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
28  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.599500  0   6   6   660 0.34299993515   0 days 00:00:00.099917000
29  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.699417  0   7   7   160 0.354000091553  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
30  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.799333  0   8   8   246 0.361999988556  0 days 00:00:00.099916000
31  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.899250  0   9   9   69  0.371000051498  0 days 00:00:00.099917000
23  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.999160  0   12  12  795 0.410000085831  0 days 00:00:00.099910000
32  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:14.999167  0   10  10  462 0.382999897003  0 days 00:00:00.000007000
33  2020-08-06  2020-10-20 18:01:15.000000  0   11  11  4   0.395999908447  0 days 00:00:00.000833000
```

Comment: You're missing the point here, there's a huge gap in time.

Comment: The huge gap between row with index 22 and 23 have a huge offset because the data frame is not sorted by the datetime.  index 24 follows 22.  There are 9 samples between 22 and 23 the way the original df is sorted.  And also you are correct that the time deltas are not even.  The second sample when sorted by time is .199833 seconds after the first sample, but the 12th sample is .000007 seconds after the 11th. However, if the goal is to take 11 samples/second they are all there in the df and nothing needs to be filled in.